# Which is the best way of parsing CSV-data in a logic app without using a custom connector?

Tags: json, csv, azure-logic-apps, data-conversion

I have an SFTP trigger in a logic app which fires when a file is added to a certain file area. It is a CSV-formatted file and I want the rows to be parsed and coverted into json. Which is the best way to convert CSV-data into json without using any custom connectors?

I cannot find any built-in connectors doing this job. And as far as I know there are no logic apps functions doing the job either.

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Answer (score 2):

1.Created logic app as shown below:

[image]

2 .Created container in storage account and uploaded a CSV file in container.

[image]

3.Next using compose action to split the contents of the CSV file on every new line into an array.

a. Here is the expression used in **SplitLines** compose action:

```
split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),decodeUriComponent('%0D%0A'))
```

b. Follow the below [MS Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference) to write expressions:

[image]4. Removing last(empty) line from previous output using another compose action as shown below ,

**`take(outputs('SplitLines'),add(length(outputs('SplitLines')),-1))`**

[image]

5.Separating field names using compose action

**`split(first(outputs('SplitLines')), ',')`**[image]

6. Forming json as shown below using Select action,

```
**From**: **`skip(outputs('RemoveLastLine'), 1)`**
**Map:**
**`outputs('SplitFieldName')[0]`** **`split(item(), ',')?[0]`**
**`outputs('SplitFieldName')[1]`** **`split(item(), ',')?[1]`**
```

[image]

7. Tested logic app and it is running successfully. ￼

[image]

8. Content of CSV file is as shown below:
   [image: 8]
9. Csv data is formatted as json:
   [image]

Reference:[Use data operations in Power Automate (contains video) — Power Automate | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/data-operations)

Credit:  @Iason Koulas

Answer (score 1):

Right now, there is no connector/action in logic app that can provide the out of box solution for your requirement. You need to [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops) in through the array and perform the calculation as per your requirement but I will not suggest you leverage the loop, variables action as it may take time and cost you more.

The alternative would be leveraging the [inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code?tabs=consumption) (JavaScript code) to do the calculation as per your requirement. Please note that you will need Integration Account to run your inline code.
Please refer to [javascript code](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/storage/attachments/19717-javascript-code.txt) and modified if needed according to your needs. I have used '_' for differentiating the nested objects. For more details you can refer to previous discussion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/72756/other-ways-to-convert-csv-to-json-more-performance.html).

For complex calculation you can offload this functionality to azure function and write your code as per the [supported languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages) and call [azure function from logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=consumption).